# Jquery 'this' keyword and selector's basic filters

Tags: jquery

When using the '**this**' keyword in jQuery, what is the syntax for adding basic filters.

For example:

```
$(this):contains('foo')

$(this):visible OR $(this:visible)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Searching for items within this:

```
$(':visible, any-selector', this)
$(this).find(':visible, any-selector')
```

if you want a true or false return:

```
if($(this).is(':visible, any-selector')){
    alert('this is visible, or matches "any-selector"');
    }
else{
    alert('this is hidden, or doesn\'t match "any-selector"');
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

That's what the filter() method is for:

```
$(this).filter(":contains(foo)");
$(this).filter(":visible")
```

According to the docs:

Removes all elements from the set of matched elements that do not match the specified expression(s).

Comment: Yes, that will filter your matched elements by your selector, but our matched elements = [this]. You've only selected "this". So if this doesn't match your selector you would have to do a .size() to tell if it matched or not... find looks inside the selected elements, and is returns a logical true / false responce of the selector on the set.

Answer (score 1):

use this syntax: `jQuery( expression, [context] )`

```
$(":contains(foo)", this)
$(":visible", this)
$("any-selector", this)
```

Comment: that's not correct. It will only select sub-elements of 'this'

Comment: the jQuery( expression, context ) is the same as jQuery(context).find(expression).

Comment: the up vote is not related to the question's answer , i was looking to know how to use the keyword `this` with other selectors